# iOS CLGeocode address dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, geocode, clgeocoder

I am trying to use CLGeocoder to reverse geocode an address and want to create an address dictionary programmatically to use to geocode with. How can I do that? I can't find anything on it! Thanks.

Comment: [What Have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well I just tried this:     NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"xxxx", kABPersonAddressProperty,
                                @"12345", kABPersonAddressStreetKey,
                                @"6789", kABPersonAddressCityKey,
                                @"10123", kABPersonAddressStateKey, nil];

and it didnt work.

Comment: Then what is holding you to include that snippet in your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work".  Would love to help but your question needs some work. Have you tried that dictionary with real values instead of the junk values you posted?

Answer (score 3):

The docs in the CLGeocoder header file give you the info you need:

```
// geocodeAddressDictionary:completionHandler: takes an address dictionary as defined by the AddressBook framework.
// You can obtain an address dictionary from an ABPerson by retrieving the kABPersonAddressProperty property.
// Alternately, one can be constructed using the kABPersonAddress* keys defined in <AddressBook/ABPerson.h>.

- (void)geocodeAddressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```